# Injector error when trying to establish routing

Tags: angularjs, ngroute

I'm testing the Angular framework, and my last tests are being based on the routing thingy.

I was making an example in which I have the typical project setup: source folder with index.html, which has this:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html ng-app="test">
    <head>
      <!-- Plugins/Frameworks !-->
      <script type="text/javascript" src="plugins/angular.js"></script>
      <script type="text/javascript" src="plugins/angular-route.js"></script>

      <!-- JS !-->
      <script type="text/javascript" src="js/app.js"></script>
      <script type="text/javascript" src="js/controllers.js"></script>
      <script type="text/javascript" src="js/directives.js"></script>
      <script type="text/javascript" src="js/services.js"></script>

      <!-- Stylesheets !-->
      <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/bootstrap.css">
      <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/styles.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div ng-view>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

And then, the folders js (with controllers, directives, module definition...), css, and plugins (where I have the angular.js and angular-route.jos).

This is what I have in my module definition at js/app.js:

```
var app = angular.module('test', ['ngRoute', 'controllers', 'directives', 'services']);

app.config(['$routeProvider',function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider.
    when('/index', {
        templateUrl: 'templates/main.html',
        controller: 'mainCtrl'
    }).
    otherwise({
        redirectTo: '/index'
    });

}]);
```

It should work when inputting localhost/testSite/index, retrieving me to this template:

```
<div class="page-header">
  <h1>Test site<small>For test purposes</small></h1>
</div>
<div class="col-xs-3 col-sm-3 col-md-3 col-lg-3 sidebar">
    Test, test, test!
</div>
```

... shouldn't it? Well, it doesn't.

I'm having this error each time I access my index.html:

Error: [$injector:modulerr] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.5.0-rc.1/$injector/modulerr?p0=test&p1=%5B%24injector%3Amodulerr%5D%20http%3A%2F%2Ferrors.angularjs.org%2F1.5.0-rc.1%2F%24injector%2Fmodulerr%3Fp0%3Ddirectives%26p1%3D%255B%2524injector%253Anomod%255D%2520http%253A%252F%252Ferrors.angularjs.org%252F1.5.0-rc.1%252F%2524injector%252Fnomod%253Fp0%253Ddirectives%250AP%252F%253C%2540http%253A%252F%252Flocalhost%252FtestSite%252Fplugins%252Fangular.js%253A6%253A421%250Afe%252F%253C%252F%253C%252F%253C%2540http%253A%252F%252Flocalhost%252FtestSite%252Fplugins%252Fangular.js%253A25%253A136%250Ab%2540http%253A%252F%252Flocalhost%252FtestSite%252Fplugins%252Fangular.js%253A24%253A188%250Afe%252F%253C%252F%253C%2540http%253A%252F%252Flocalhost%252FtestSite%252Fplugins%252Fangular.js%253A24%253A1%250Ag%252F%253C%2540http%253A%252F%252Flocalhost%252FtestSite%252Fplugins%252Fangular.js%253A39%253A201%250An%2540http%253A%252F%252Flocalhost%252FtestSite%252Fplugins%252Fangular.js%253A7%253A364%250Ag%2540http%253A%252F%252Flocalhost%252FtestSite%252Fplugins%252Fangular.js%253A39%253A49%250Ag%252F%253C%2540http%253A%252F%252Flocalhost%252FtestSite%252Fplugins%252Fangular.js%253A39%253A218%250An%2540http%253A%252F%252Flocalhost%252FtestSite%252Fplugins%252Fangular.js%253A7%253A364%250Ag%2540http%253A%252F%252Flocalhost%252FtestSite%252Fplugins%252Fangular.js%253A39%253A49%250Agb%2540http%253A%252F%252Flocalhost%252FtestSite%252Fplugins%252Fangular.js%253A43%253A53%250Azc%252Fc%2540http%253A%252F%252Flocalhost%252FtestSite%252Fplugins%252Fangular.js%253A20%253A421%250Azc%2540http%253A%252F%252Flocalhost%252FtestSite%252Fplugins%252Fangular.js%253A21%253A225%250Aae%2540http%253A%252F%252Flocalhost%252FtestSite%252Fplugins%252Fangular.js%253A20%253A41%250A%2540http%253A%252F%252Flocalhost%252FtestSite%252Fplugins%252Fangular.js%253A304%253A355%250Ab%2540http%253A%252F%252Flocalhost%252FtestSite%252Fplugins%252Fangular.js%253A181%253A440%250AMf%2540http%253A%252F%252Flocalhost%252FtestSite%252Fplugins%252Fangular.js%253A36%253A391%250ALf%252Fd%2540http%253A%252F%252Flocalhost%252FtestSite%252Fplugins%252Fangular.js%253A36%253A340%250A%0AP%2F%3C%40http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%2FtestSite%2Fplugins%2Fangular.js%3A6%3A421%0Ag%2F%3C%40http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%2FtestSite%2Fplugins%2Fangular.js%3A39%3A475%0An%40http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%2FtestSite%2Fplugins%2Fangular.js%3A7%3A364%0Ag%40http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%2FtestSite%2Fplugins%2Fangular.js%3A39%3A49%0Ag%2F%3C%40http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%2FtestSite%2Fplugins%2Fangular.js%3A39%3A218%0An%40http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%2FtestSite%2Fplugins%2Fangular.js%3A7%3A364%0Ag%40http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%2FtestSite%2Fplugins%2Fangular.js%3A39%3A49%0Agb%40http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%2FtestSite%2Fplugins%2Fangular.js%3A43%3A53%0Azc%2Fc%40http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%2FtestSite%2Fplugins%2Fangular.js%3A20%3A421%0Azc%40http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%2FtestSite%2Fplugins%2Fangular.js%3A21%3A225%0Aae%40http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%2FtestSite%2Fplugins%2Fangular.js%3A20%3A41%0A%40http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%2FtestSite%2Fplugins%2Fangular.js%3A304%3A355%0Ab%40http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%2FtestSite%2Fplugins%2Fangular.js%3A181%3A440%0AMf%40http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%2FtestSite%2Fplugins%2Fangular.js%3A36%3A391%0ALf%2Fd%40http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%2FtestSite%2Fplugins%2Fangular.js%3A36%3A340%0A

What may be causing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This errors messages are really annoying to read but here is the transalation : no mod 'directives' for module 'test' :

Error: [$injector:modulerr] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.5.0-rc.1/$injector/modulerr?p0=**test**&p1=%5B%24injector%3Amodulerr%5D%20http%3A%2F%2Ferrors.angularjs.org%2F1.5.0-rc.1%2F%24injector%2Fmodulerr%3Fp0%3D**directives**%26p1%3D%255B%2524injector%253A**nomod**%255D%2520http%253A%252F%252Ferrors.angularjs.org%252F1.5.0-rc.1%252F%2524injector%252F**nomod**%253Fp0%253D**directives**

SO check your declaration of your module directives.

Comment: Oh, thank you! Yes, I was indeed having a problem in the directives  module. Now it's fixed and it works so greatly. Thank you!

Comment: you're welcome, those messages gave me quite a headache when i started angular too :)